# Does the Hunter's Mark spell stack with the Rogue's Sneak Attack feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rogue, sneak-attack, stacking

Wondering if when multi classing a ranger and a rogue, can the spell hunters mark stack with sneak attack on damage roll?

For reference, [*hunter's mark*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark) states:

> You choose a creature you can see within range and mystically mark it as your quarry. Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 damage to the target whenever you hit it with a weapon attack [...]

And [Sneak Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#SneakAttack-343) states:

> [...] Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon [...]

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 26):

## Hunter's Mark and Sneak Attack stack

When [Combining Game Effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#CombiningGameEffects), effects stack unless they have the same name, or otherwise specifically say they do not stack:

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap.

Since Hunter's Mark and Sneak Attack are different game features and they don't say otherwise, they stack.